# SELECTing multiple values for the same attribute using FOR XML in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath

I'm attempting to retrieve data from a SQL table as XML.  Consider the following table:

```
                  Customers      
Id      Last      First      Phone1      Phone2  
10      Doe       John      555-2121    555-6145
33     Smith      Sally     555-3333    555-7000
```

I'd like to retrieve the Last, First, Phone1, and Phone2 fields using the FOR XML clause in SQL.  However, I'd like to retrieve the Phone2 field with an attribute of "Evening".  For example, I'd like the XML to look like:

```
<Customers>   
  <Customer>
        <Last>Doe</Last>
        <First>John</First>
        <Phone Type="Daytime">555-2121</Phone>
        <Phone Type="Evening">555-6145</Phone>   
  </Customer> 
</Customers>
```

However, I'm unable to get it to work.  Is there something I'm missing?  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the nodes in a subquery.  If you specify `for xml type`, the subqueries merge with the outer query to give one XML:

```
select  Last as [Last]
,       First as [First]
,       (
        select  'Daytime' as [@Type]
        ,       Phone1 as [*]
        for xml path('Phone'), type
        )
,       (
        select  'Evening' as [@Type]
        ,       Phone2 as [*]
        for xml path('Phone'), type
        )
from    Customers
for xml path('Customer'), root('Customers')
```

This prints:

```
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <Last>Doe</Last>
        <First>John</First>
        <Phone Type="Daytime">555-2121</Phone>
        <Phone Type="Evening">555-6145</Phone>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Last>Smith</Last>
        <First>Sally</First>
        <Phone Type="Daytime">555-3333</Phone>
        <Phone Type="Evening">555-7000</Phone>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7835/25/0)